# calculation in Python DataFrame loop for trade management

Tags: python

I have a for loop with nested if else statements. What I am trying to do is for each row in my DataFrame

1. check if a trade is open by checking if a TP or SL has already been set. If it has move on to the next row, because I don't want to open a trade when one is already running.
2. If a trade isn't open, determine if the trade needs to be a buy or sell, then set TP and SL accordingly. As well as keeping track of the entry price.
3. Now if trade is open we are to check if our current price has hit our TP or SL Level and if so record the profit or loss by subtracting our entry price from the exit level, and recording it in the dataframe.

I keep getting a negative profit column and my loss column is not showing up at all, hinting that there aren't any calculated losses. What is wrong with my logic here?

```
# Initialize TP and SL levels
TP_level = 0.0
SL_level = 0.0
entry = 0.0

# Iterate over rows in the DataFrame
for index, row in df_H1.iterrows():
    # Check if the trade is opened
    if row['IS_TRADE'] == 'NO':
        continue

    else:
        # If trade is already open, skip
        if TP_level != 0.0 or SL_level != 0.0:
            continue
        # Set TP and SL levels based on the trade type
        elif row['TRIGGER'] == 'BUY':
            TP_level = row['R2']  # Set TP level to R2
            SL_level = row['S1']  # Set SL level to S1
            entry = row['mid_c']
        elif row['TRIGGER'] == 'SELL':
            TP_level = row['S2']  # Set TP level to S2
            SL_level = row['R1']  # Set SL level to R1
            entry = row['mid_c']
    
        # Check if the price reaches TP level
        if row['mid_c'] >= TP_level:
            # Close the trade and calculate the profit
            profit = TP_level - entry
            # Reset TP and SL levels
            TP_level = 0.0
            SL_level = 0.0
            # Update the profit in the DataFrame
            df_H1.at[index, 'PROFIT'] = profit
        # Check if the price reaches SL level
        elif row['mid_c'] <= SL_level:
            # Close the trade and calculate the loss
            loss = SL_level - entry
            # Reset TP and SL levels
            TP_level = 0.0
            SL_level = 0.0
            entry = 0.0
            # Update the loss in the DataFrame
            df_H1.at[index, 'LOSS'] = loss

# Check for any remaining open trades and calculate their profits or losses
if TP_level != 0.0 or SL_level != 0.0:
    if row['TRIGGER'] == 'BUY':
        profit = TP_level - row['mid_c']
        df_H1.at[index, 'PROFIT'] = profit
    elif row['TRIGGER'] == 'SELL':
        loss = SL_level - row['mid_c']
        df_H1.at[index, 'LOSS'] = loss

# Check for any remaining open trades and calculate their profits or losses
for index, row in df_H1.iterrows():
    if row['IS_TRADE'] == 'YES':
        if TP_level != 0.0 or SL_level != 0.0:
            if row['TRIGGER'] == 'BUY':
                profit = TP_level - row['mid_c']
                df_H1.at[index, 'PROFIT'] = profit
            elif row['TRIGGER'] == 'SELL':
                loss = SL_level - row['mid_c']
                df_H1.at[index, 'LOSS'] = loss
```